# Sage newbie; introducing symbols (variables) inside vectors and matrices

Tags: python, linear-algebra, symbolic-math, sage

I would like to have linear algebra operations to be evaluated with symbols instead of numerically.
For example, having the following matrix:

```
A = matrix(QQ,[
    [ 2,  1,  2, -6],
    [-1,  2,  1,  7],
    [ 3, -1, -3, -1],
    [ 1,  5,  6,  0],
    [ 2,  2,  1,  1]
    ])
```

I would like to multiply for a vector with symbolic variables as follows:

```
t = 'real'
var('x1')
assume(x1, t)
var('x2')
assume(x2, t)
var('x3')
assume(x3, t)
var('x4')
assume(x4, t)
xx = vector(QQ, [x1, x2, x3, x4])
A * xx.transpose()
```

Unfortunately building the `xx` vector is unsuccessful, producing this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot evaluate symbolic expression to a numeric value.
```

This does not work, so how can I use symbols in Sage's linear algebra framework?

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to work with entries in a polynomial ring.

```
sage: R.<x1,x2,x3,x4> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
sage: R
Multivariate Polynomial Ring in x1, x2, x3, x4 over Rational Field
```

Then define your vector with coordinates in `R`.

```
sage: xx = vector(R,[x1,x2,x3,x4])
sage: A * xx
```

The result is another vector with entries in `R`.

Another solution is to work in the symbolic ring `SR`, as pointed out by @kcrisman on ask-sage.